# How to avoid duplicate values during joining of 2 table using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am learning databases and I am using SQL Server 2008. When I go through the concept of join, I found the problem of duplication of data on table. I tried to avoid duplicate values by using distinct keyword but it's not working. I show you my table structure, query which I am trying and required output. Thank you in advance.

**Table 1**:

```
id    GroupName
---------------
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

**Table 2**:

```
id     ItemName   Gid
----------------------
1        aa       1
2        bb       1
3        cc       1
4        dd       2
5        ee       2
6        ff       3
7        gg       3
```

This is the query which I am using

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    T2.ItemName, T1.GroupName 
FROM 
    TABLE2 T2 
JOIN 
    TABLE1 T1 ON T1.ID = T2.GID 
ORDER BY 
    T2.ItemName, T1.GroupName
```

Output I am getting is this:

```
ItemName      GroupName
------------------------
  aa           A
  bb           A
  cc           A
  dd           B
  ee           B
  ff           C
  gg           C
```

but I need this output instead:

```
ItemName    GroupName
----------------------
  aa           A
  bb  
  cc
  dd           B
  ee   
  ff           C
  gg
```

Comment: I don't really see the point of the join, since each group is present in the second table.  Could you update the question to show why a join might be necessary?

Comment: @tim biegeleisen thank you that was by mistake i wrote now its proper

Comment: What do you mean by 'duplicate value'? Because the existing code will show something like:
aa A / bb A / cc A / dd B / etc. - and that's not the duplicates - these are different values.

Comment: Firstly, you need to show us what you are actually getting. We can assume, but "assumption is the mother of all problems". But if I do go ahead and assume what your output is, I'd tell you that you are confusing a database operation with a 'presentation' operation.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Check now

Comment: There is *no duplicate value* - each row returned from your query is unique in itself, and therefore relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not get that output as you described. Because using left or right outer join also not get the desired output.

I tried this :

```
select distinct i.Item_Name, g.GrpName 
from ItemMaster i right outer join GrpDetail g
on i.Id = g.Id
order by i.Item_Name, g.GrpName;
```

And also tried :

```
select distinct i.Item_Name, g.GrpName 
from ItemMaster i left outer join GrpDetail g
on i.Id = g.Id
order by i.Item_Name, g.GrpName;
```

There are no diffrence in output.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the "first" row to get a match, then you can use `row_number()`.  Here is one way without a subquery:

```
SELECT T2.ItemName,
       (CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY T2.ItemName ORDER BY ID) = 1
             THEN T1.GroupName 
        END) as GroupName
FROM TABLE2 T2  JOIN
     TABLE1 T1 
     ON T1.ID = T2.GID 
ORDERY BY T2.ItemName, T1.GroupName;
```

Note:  The data suggest that the `JOIN` is on `GroupName`.  However, it is more reasonable to use the `Id` for the foreign key.

Comment: its shows this error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'A' to data type int."

Comment: @darshandave . . . As my comment suggested, your original data had misleading columns.

Answer (score 1):

Sql results must be in a row-column format.  Each row is known as a "relation".  The relations are not supposed to think about each other.

When you join a parent table to a child table, the parent values will be duplicated in the result.  This is because each row in the result represents a fact about the child table.

The duplication is a natural effect of the join.

Comment: Ok i got your point so it seems we can not avoid duplicate values while joining parent table to child right?

Answer (score -4):

Are you tried left or right outer join ??
Try right outer join I think that the solution of your query.